# factoextra: jitter labels to avoid overplotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, factoextra

Since `factoextra` uses the `ggplot2` plotting system, is there a way to adjust the positioning of text labels (jitter), in order to avoid overlapping?

```
# install.packages("devtools","FactoMineR")
# library("devtools")
# install_github("kassambara/factoextra")

library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")

data(poison)
poison.active <- poison[1:55, 5:15]
res.mca <- MCA(poison.active, graph = FALSE)
fviz_mca_ind(res.mca)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## factoextra: Reduce overplotting

The argument **jitter** is now available in factoextra package and documented at : http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factoextra-reduce-overplotting-of-points-and-labels-r-software-and-data-mining.

> Install the latest version of factoextra (>= 1.0.3) as follow:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/factoextra")
```

### Compute Multiple Correspondence Analysis

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")

# Load data
data(poison)
poison.active <- poison[1:55, 5:15]
# Compute MCA
res.mca <- MCA(poison.active, graph = FALSE)
```

### Default plot

```
# Default plot
fviz_mca_ind(res.mca)
```

[image]

### Use jitter to reduce overplotting

```
Use jitter to reduce overplotting
fviz_mca_ind(res.mca, jitter = list(width = 0.3, height = 0.3))
```

Note that the argument jitter is a list of **width** and **height** parameters:

- width: degree of jitter in x direction
- height: degree of jitter in y direction

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your work. Just one more question. Is it possible to jitter just the text labels, without changing the correct position for points?

Comment: A bit late but see this page for jittered labels: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factoextra-reduce-overplotting-of-points-and-labels-r-software-and-data-mining